# I am trying to import json file into neo4j,

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am getting this message

> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input '@': expected whitespace, a property key name, '}', an identifier or UnsignedDecimalInteger (line 1, column 152 (offset: 151))

This is the code i used in cypher query

> CALL apoc.load.json("file:///C:/Users/C63086/Downloads/neo4j-community-3.4.0/naveen.export.json") YIELD value AS E2812HA0011EP MERGE (u:E2812HA0011EP {rid: E2812HA0011EP.@rid}) SET u.actualR = E2812HA0011EP.actualR, u.sumPartno = E2812HA0011EP.sumPartno, u.comments = E2812HA0011EP.comments, u.Partno = E2812HA0011EP.Partno, u.title = E2812HA0011EP.title, u.priority = E2812HA0011EP.priority, u.expectedR = E2812HA0011EP.expectedR, u.configid = E2812HA0011EP.configid, u.subtitle = E2812HA0011EP.subtitle, u.Qty = E2812HA0011EP.Qty, u.model = E2812HA0011EP.model, u.family = E2812HA0011EP.family, u.sku = E2812HA0011EP.sku, u.bundle = E2812HA0011EP.bundle

So, is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: Looks like @rid is not an authorized name. If you cant get it renamed, use its position in the resulting array like   E2812HA0011EP[xx] with xx th position.
Also rename E2812HA0011EP , you use it as a label too. Just use "line" to get a more readable code

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read a property called `@rid`, but the `@` is a special charater.
So you need to escape the name of this property by putting `back quote` like this :

```
 ... E2812HA0011EP.`@rid` ...
```